# Missing grants in /beta/oAuth2Permissiongrants Graph call

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When we fetch a specific customer's oAuth2 grants (`beta/<tenant_id>/oAuth2Permissiongrants`), we are getting just 3 grants each one with an empty scope :

```json
[{
    "consentType": "AllPrincipals",
    "resourceId": "xxxxxxx-b2e2-42d8-9586-21aa24c78412",
    "expiryTime": "2017-08-27T10:19:35.8989022Z",
    "principalId": None,
    "clientId": "xxxxxxx-bd4a-4ac5-ad18-ee304693a3ee",
    "startTime": "2016-02-27T10:19:35.8989022Z",
    "scope": "",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxx4wRpOj7nrF0zXisthClYYhqiTHhBI"
}, {
    "consentType": "AllPrincipals",
    "resourceId": "xxxxxxxx-b2e2-42d8-9586-21aa24c78412",
    "expiryTime": "2018-03-01T15:16:24.8088543Z",
    "principalId": None,
    "clientId": "xxxxxxxx-633d-4f27-9d07-fe3f95aaa41c",
    "startTime": "2016-09-01T15:16:24.8088543Z",
    "scope": "",
    "id": "xxxxxxxx-dB_4_laqkHHrF0zXisthClYYhqiTHhBI"
}, {
    "consentType": "AllPrincipals",
    "resourceId": "xxxxxxx-b2e2-42d8-9586-21aa24c78412",
    "expiryTime": "2017-12-13T15:30:31.8853053Z",
    "principalId": None,
    "clientId": "xxxxxxxx-c2a8-4f2d-92d5-f4e41f82ad4c",
    "startTime": "2016-06-13T15:30:31.8853053Z",
    "scope": "",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxx-S1fTkH4KtTHrF0zXisthClYYhqiTHhBI"
}]
```

We know for sure that this customer should have dozens of oAuth2 grants which we were expecting to see in the API response.

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: I believe the URI should be `beta/oAuth2Permissiongrants` (no tenant id)

Comment: Unfortunately, same results with that URI

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT - thank you for the quick response. I wonder if you would have another idea what could cause this, as i know for sure that this customer have many oAuth2 user grants.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you expected to see but didn't? It might help to understand what is missing.

Comment: We except to see many "Principal" grants (consentType) that supposed to be in the response. This customer is actually very big (~1000 users) so getting in this call only 3 grants doesn't make sense. An example of missing grant would be -

Comment: {u'consentType': u'Principal', u'resourceId': u'029ac8fe-e9a6-4897-a9a6-e887e3cfc75a', u'expiryTime': u'2017-12-18T15:14:17.7650079Z', u'principalId': u'2603f31e-f797-478f-8808-25f23ce87f33', u'clientId': u'11e51223-6c4a-4716-a783-9be1689a1fcb', u'startTime': u'0001-01-01T00:00:00Z', u'scope': u'User.Read', u'id': u'IxLlEUpsFkeng5vhaJofy_7ImgKm6ZdIqaboh-PPx1oe8wMml_ePR4gIJfI86H8z'}

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT also note that the 3 grants we are getting has an empty scopes which is weird by itself.

Comment: @ArielCloudlock Is the relative info show up when you register a new application and grant the permission in this tenant? And since you mentioned, you were fetching a  specific customer's oAuth2 grants, did you specific the user in the request?